# How to create a web service with binary encrypted XML requests?

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, encryption, binary

I'm trying to create a web service that can get an encrypted XML request and work with it, instead of the regular XML SOAP messages, can this be done? If so, how? What sort of protocol do I need?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [RESTful webservice](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-restful/) instead of SOAP if you want to, and make the transaction over `HTTPS` to be even more secure.